# How do I move file types not a specific file in PyCharm?

Tags: python, file-organization

I am trying to make a program to organize my downloads folder every time I download something, but if I use this code:

```py
import shutil

shutil.move("/Users/plapl/downloads/.zip", "/Users/plapl/Desktop/Shortcuts/winrar files")
shutil.move("/Users/plapl/downloads/.png", "/Users/plapl/Desktop/Shortcuts/images")
```

It searches for a file name called .zip and .png, but I want it to search for all files that are that type. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to iterate over the files in the directory. Here is an example from [source](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/os/python-the-shutil-module)

```
import shutil
import os
source = os.listdir("/Users/plapl/downloads/")
destination = "/Users/plapl/Desktop/Shortcuts/winrar files"
for files in source:
    if files.endswith(".zip"):
        shutil.move(files,destination)
```

Answer (score 0):

I made something based off of that,          but it says unresolved reference 'file'

```
import shutil

import os


source = os.listdir("/Users/plapl/Downloads/")

destination1 = "/Users/plapl/desktop/Shortcuts/images"

destination2 = "/Users/plapl/Shortcuts/winrar files"

destination3 = "/Users/plapl/torrents"

for files in source:
    if file.endswith(".png"):
        shutil.move(files, destination1)

    if file.endswith(".zip"):
        shutil.move(files, destination2)

    if file.endswith(".torrent"):
        shutil.move(files, destination3)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is complaining for the variable name `file` which is not defined.

You should use `files` since that is your iterating variable name.

Comment: Thanks, that helped but I ran into another error, it chooses a random file that has that type of ending, FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '(file's name).torrent'

Comment: The problem is you are providing only the file name to the move operation and it would look in the current directory where you are executing the code from. Hence you should pass the entire path of the file to the move operation.  

`dir_name = "/Users/plapl/Downloads/" #<the path you used to get the source>
for files in source:
    if files.endswith(".pdf"):
         shutil.move(os.path.join(dir_name, files), destination3)`